# how to subtract the first line from the next in column sap bo webi

Tags: business-objects, webi

Column1: [pz] line_index
type: number
= RowIndex () + 1

Column 2: Inc.
Enter the text
* each event number is unique

Column 3: audit time
type: date and time

Example:

[pz] row_index
29
audit time:
1/8/2019 08:08:06

subtract:

[pz] row_index
26
audit time:
1/8/2019 08:02:27

Return result.

I need him to take every position (2 each), and return the result, starting from the beginning.

Comment: So are you looking for the difference in minutes for each row in comparison with the first row?

Comment: no, we count the differences between each of the records separately

Answer (score 0):

I am struggling to understand your requirement, but I'll give it a try and maybe this will spark an idea for you to get what you need.

I adapted this answer from this [forum post](http://www.forumtopics.com/busobj/viewtopic.php?p=895382). It is noted there that 4.2 SP5 has some timestamp difference functions. Until then create a variable called **Minutes Elapsed from Previous** with this definition...

```
=If (Not(IsNull(Previous([Audit Datetime])));
(
(
(
ToNumber( Substr( FormatDate( [Audit Datetime] ;"HH:mm:ss" ) ; 1 ; 2 ) ) * 60 * 60 +
ToNumber( Substr( FormatDate( [Audit Datetime] ;"HH:mm:ss" ) ; 4 ; 2 ) ) * 60 +
ToNumber( Substr( FormatDate( [Audit Datetime] ;"HH:mm:ss" ) ; 7 ; 2 ) )
)
-
(
ToNumber( Substr( FormatDate( Previous([Audit Datetime]) ; "HH:mm:ss" ) ; 1 ;2 ) ) * 60 * 60 +
ToNumber( Substr( FormatDate( Previous([Audit Datetime]) ; "HH:mm:ss" ) ; 4 ; 2) ) * 60 +
ToNumber( Substr( FormatDate( Previous([Audit Datetime]) ; "HH:mm:ss" ) ; 7 ; 2) )
)
)
) / 60 +
( DaysBetween( Previous([Audit Datetime]) ; [Audit Datetime] ) * 24 * 60 ))
```

Basically you convert the time portion of **Audit Datetime** to seconds, subtract the time portion of the **Previous([Audit Datetime])** converted to seconds, convert it back to minutes and add a day's worth of minutes if a full day as passed. I wrapped it all in an if statement so that if your first row's difference is blank since there isn't a previous row to compare.

I am unclear if that is what you are after. From other comments, it seems you may be wanting to find the difference between the Audit Datetime for each row and the first Audit Datetime. To do that I created a variable called **First Audit Datetime** as follows...

```
=Min([Audit Datetime]) In Block
```

The "In Block" portion is important so that you get the minimum Audit Datetime for the entire table. Then you can create a variable called **Minutes Elapsed from Start** like this...

```
=If (Not(IsNull(Previous([Audit Datetime])));
(
(
(
ToNumber( Substr( FormatDate( [Audit Datetime] ;"HH:mm:ss" ) ; 1 ; 2 ) ) * 60 * 60 +
ToNumber( Substr( FormatDate( [Audit Datetime] ;"HH:mm:ss" ) ; 4 ; 2 ) ) * 60 +
ToNumber( Substr( FormatDate( [Audit Datetime] ;"HH:mm:ss" ) ; 7 ; 2 ) )
)
-
(
ToNumber( Substr( FormatDate( [First Audit Datetime] ; "HH:mm:ss" ) ; 1 ;2 ) ) * 60 * 60 +
ToNumber( Substr( FormatDate( [First Audit Datetime] ; "HH:mm:ss" ) ; 4 ; 2) ) * 60 +
ToNumber( Substr( FormatDate( [First Audit Datetime] ; "HH:mm:ss" ) ; 7 ; 2) )
)
)
) / 60 +
( DaysBetween( [First Audit Datetime] ; [Audit Datetime] ) * 24 * 60 ))
```

You could also create a **Minutes Elapsed Running Sum** variable that uses **Minutes Elapsed from Previous** to get the same result as **Minutes Elapsed from Start** without having to create the **First Audit Datetime** variable...

```
=RunningSum([Minutes Elapsed from Previous])
```

Here is what that looks like with all three minutes elapsed variables...

[image]

If that is not what you want, please provide a table of source values and the expected result. Giving a written description of the values and expected result is helpful, but not enough.

Comment: Yes I know, I used it.
However, I want to develop it so that it refers to me, an example:
index 1, time: 8:00 AM
index 2, time: 8:20 AM
index 3, time: 9:00 AM

Goal:
Calculate the difference for each of them separately:
time from:
index 2 - index 1 = 20 min
index 3 - index 2 = 40 min

Now:
Calculates me from index 1 to index 3

Comment: With the Previous function you can specify an offset to skip more than one record. You could also look into using the RelativeValue function.

Comment: Can you help me create a sample formula?
Index: row_index, for each row
Audit Date: time of status change
I need to calculate: reaction time, as I wrote above.

Comment: I'll try. Could please edit your question with a complete sample of data and the expected result?

Comment: no, we count the differences between each of the records separately